# XCode autocompletes the quotations and parens when typing a string. Is there a hotkey to jump to the next line when I'm done typing the string?

Tags: xcode

For example when I start typing the opening `("` it automatically adds `")` with the cursor inside of the string.
Is there a way to go to the next line after finishing the string without reaching for the mouse?

I've tried a million hotkey combos and googling it but it seems like there's no way around having to use the mouse to get out of the string contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode supports some Emacs cursor movement shortcuts by default. Here are some that might be relevant to your question:

- <kbd>control-e</kbd> moves to the **e**nd of the current line.
- <kbd>control-n</kbd> moves down to the **n**ext line (while trying to preserve the horizontal position of the cursor).
- <kbd>control-p</kbd> moves up to the **p**revious line (while trying to preserve the horizontal position of the cursor).
- <kbd>control-f</kbd> moves **f**orward one character, including newlines.
- <kbd>control-b</kbd> moves **b**ackward one character, including newlines.

So, depending on exactly what you want, you might be happy just pressing <kbd>control-n</kbd>, or you might prefer to press <kbd>control-e</kbd> followed by <kbd>control-f</kbd>, or maybe you want to press <kbd>control-e</kbd> and then <kbd>return</kbd>.

Also, Xcode supports “overtyping” for some characters. If the insertion point is just before a `”`, `)`, `]`, or `}`, you can usually just type that character to move past it without inserting another. So if the cursor is just before `”)`, you can type `”)` to move past those two characters without changing the file.